# problem on using crystal report in MVC C# redirect aspx from controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I using the sample code from this blog https://www.mysharings.com/coderblog/how-to-use-crystal-reports-in-asp-net-mvc/
It works OK, I can export my old crystal report to PDF. But it calls the aspx from javascript. I try to call it from the controller, it nothing gets exported even if debugging inside aspx.cs, after running though the code it's not exporting the PDF.

At the end both code samples will call `objReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, response, true, fileName);`
Since they redirect to the same aspx file and they are getting the same DataTable from mssql how come direct from javascript works but it fails on direct from controller? Any idea?

I try to use redirection , `service.execute`, and `response.redirect` but still got the same error.

I wondered if that is like that because I needed to add the attribute on `reportframe` from the controller so I used

```
var myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("ReportFrame");
myDiv.Attributes.Add("src", path);
```

but it still does not work.

=========== code call from Javascript ========================================

```
<input id="report" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Report" 
onclick="PrintReport('pdf'); />

 <iframe id="ReportFrame" src="" width="100%" height="1000" style="display:none"></iframe>

function PrintReport(printType) {

    if (printType == 'inline') {
        //you can add the loading.....

    }

//var params = "param1=;param2=";//create the parameters for report
var params = '';
//load the report by iframe
$("#ReportFrame").attr("src", "@Url.Content("~/Report/ReportViewer.aspx? 
Params=")" + params + "&ReportName=PrintConsumerInfoBS&SaveName=Testing 
 Report&ReportType=" + printType + "&ReportPath=WebListReports");

    $('#ReportFrame').load(function () {
        //and stop the loading after load

    });
}
```

===========================Code call from controller===========================

```
<input id="report" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Report" 
/> 


    <iframe id="ReportFrame" src="" width="100%" height="1000" style="display:none"></iframe>

 $('#report').click(function () {
    var url = '/Consumer/ExportConsumer';
    var formName = '#Consumerform';
    Global.postData(formName, url)

 })
```

and C#

```
public ActionResult ExportConsumer(ConsumerJson jsn)
{          
    //var Consumer = ConsumerAction.Report(jsn.c_uci);
        var EmptyPara = "";
        var reportType = "PDF";
        var reportFolder = "WebListReports";
        var reportName = "PrintConsumerInfoBS";
        var path = "~/Report/ReportViewer.aspx?Params=" + EmptyPara.Trim()
            + "&ReportName=" + reportName.Trim() 
            + "&SaveName="+ reportName.Trim() 
            + "&ReportType="  + reportType.Trim()
            + "&ReportPath="+ reportFolder.Trim();
   //var myDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("ReportFrame");
   //myDiv.Attributes.Add("src", path);

Response.Redirect(path);
return ReturnConsumerProfile();
}
```

Nothing download or export call from controller